# I am trying to use scanner outside the main method, and it keeps repeating after 3 inputs

Tags: java, object, java.util.scanner

So I am trying to use scanner outside main method and keeps on repeating on enter, and idk if the new Obj is causing it cause I observed that the number of obj I created is the same as the amount of times I repeated input process and enter. Then after those tries it will then show the output inside the main method.

This is my code:

```
package galitkami;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    {System.out.print("Enter Carat Value: ");}
    int c = myObj.nextInt();
    double g = 0.20;
    double cg = c*g;
    double gm = cg*1000;
    double mg = gm*0.00220462/1000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test a = new test();
        test b = new test();
        test c = new test();
       
        System.out.println("Carats in Grams: "+a.cg);
        System.out.println("Grams in Milligrams: "+b.gm);
        System.out.println("Milligrams in Pounds: "+c.mg);

    }
    
}
```

I am expecting that after I input value on "Enter Carat Value:" it will automatically show the output inside the main method.

**Update,** I have found a solution for this and this is what it looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    static Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    {System.out.print("Enter Carat Value: ");}
    final int c = myObj.nextInt();
   
    double g = 0.20;
    double cg = c*g;
    double gm = cg*1000;
    double mg = gm*0.00220462/1000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test a = new test();
   

       
      
        System.out.println("Carats in Grams: "+a.cg);
        System.out.println("Grams in Milligrams: "+a.gm);
        System.out.println("Milligrams in Pounds: "+a.mg);
    

   
}   
}
```

My friend told me that I have simply need to create one object and call it out for all.

Comment: You should not have code outside of functions (or static blocks). Move the code into the `main` method. Your code currently runs 3 times because you create 3 test objects, and for each it will run the unnamed block that asks for input.

Comment: Hello! As for I I have code outside main method, it is because our professor thought us that way because we are learning about the topic on how to create objects and he told us to initialize outside main method. And as for the 3 test objects, I found a solution for that from a friend that I should only create one object and use that for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your level of expertise in programming and Java. However there are a few things that I believe are strongly recommended to follow. Don't use a `Scanner` outside a method. Never print outside a method. Initiate all class attributes that aren't immutable inside a class constructor call.

In your current code you have three calls to `new test();` where each call will initiate all class attributes and hence the line `int c = myObj.nextInt();` will be executed three times.

Instead create a constructor method in your `Test` class. Initiate all your attributes here and execute all `System.out` prints here or in the main method.

```
public class Test {
    //Declare attributes only
    int c;
    double g, cg, gm, mg;

    //Class constructor method
    public Test(Scanner myObj) {
        System.out.print("Enter Carat Value: ");
        //Give declared attributes their values
        c = myObj.nextInt();
        g = 0.20;
        cg = c*g;
        gm = cg*1000;
        mg = gm*0.00220462/1000;
        
        System.out.println("Carats in Grams: "+ cg);
        System.out.println("Grams in Milligrams: "+ gm);
        System.out.println("Milligrams in Pounds: "+ mg);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Calling new Test() executes the constructor method above
        new Test(myObj);
        
        myObj.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I would try to note this and keep this in mind. I have a solution however for my problem.  I would include the code above.

Comment: My level of expertise in java is not that great as this is the first time I will be learning this as a freshman taking BSIT course.